# How to Execute a Function Inside a Stateless Component for Testing in Jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming, jestjs, enzyme, recompose

I've got a parent component that I've wrapped with Recompose `withHandlers` HOC. I've got a function called `removeGiftHandler` that I want to pass down to the child component as a callback that will change the state kept in the props in the parent component (using `withState`).

I'm currently testing the parent component, specifically the `removeGiftHandler` function. The problem is that because the function is being passed down to the child component, there's no event for me to simulate. Also if it was a class component I could use `wrapper.instance().removeGift(id)` and there would be no issue. Given that it is a stateless functional component, this isn't the case.

Here's the code for the component:

```
const App = ({ addGiftHandler, state: { gifts } }) => (
    <div>
        <h1>Gift Giver</h1>
        <ListGroup>
            {map(
                ({ id }) => (
                    <ListGroupItem key={id}>
                        <Gift />
                    </ListGroupItem>
                ),
                gifts
            )}
        </ListGroup>
        <Button outline onClick={addGiftHandler}>
            Add Gift
        </Button>
    </div>
)

export default compose(
    withEnhancedState(INITIAL_STATE),
    withHandlers({
        addGiftHandler: ({ state: { gifts }, updateState }) => () =>
            updateState({ gifts: [...gifts, { id: inc(length(gifts)) }] }),
        removeGiftHandler: ({ state: { gifts }, updateState }) => id => () =>
            updateState({ gifts: filter(gift => gift.id !== id, gifts) }),
    })
)(App)
```

Once `removeGiftHandler` is properly tested, the plan is to pass it down to the `Gift` component.

And here's the relevant code for the tests:

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import { length } from 'ramda'

import App from '.'

const getBaseApp = app =>
    app
        .dive()
        .dive()
        .dive()

describe('App', () => {
    const app = shallow(<App />)
    const baseApp = getBaseApp(app)

        //...

        describe('and the user wants to remove the added gift', () => {
            beforeEach(() => {
                //-----> trigger removeGiftHandler somehow <-----
            })

            it('removes the gift from `state`', () => {
                expect(app.props().state.gifts).toEqual([])
            })
        })
    })
})
```

Note `baseApp` is the base component without the Recompose HOCs.

Can someone please help me with this issue?

Comment: Maybe you can just dive 2 times instead of 3, so you would get the `withHandlers` part and call the function and check that the state has updated, but I'm no sure this will work. How we are doing it is to split the view from the recompose, so instead of returning `compose(...)(Component)` we just have one file return `compose(...)` one file returning the component and an `index.js` that just return `logic(View)`. With this approach we can easily test the recompose part and the render function isolated.

Comment: How to go about testing the compose(...) part separately?

Comment: have a look this gist: https://gist.github.com/eskimoblood/20fcc8b7994c1abcb192a07936885a4f

Comment: @AndreasKöberle Diving twice did indeed work. Thank you for taking the time to write the gist. I'm sorry I didn't get back to you sooner. I'll definitely keep this pattern of testing compose(...) separately in the back of my mind in case I need to use it sometime in the future.

Comment: Ok I will provide it as an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to dive 2 times instead of 3 to reach the `withHandlers` HOC. On the props there you can call the function and check the state was updated correctly.